# How important is JavaScript efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm working with a lot of JavaScript. Because I still have my student license, I'm using PhpStorm to develop. Okay, so I basically have to use JavaScript for almost everything (don't say this is bad, this isn't my idea). This means loading items, filling a table, opening a dialog to add a new item, opening a dialog to edit an item. Everything has to work without page refreshes or other pages. However, PhpStorm always say something about jQuery inefficiency. I kind of wonder how important it is.

For example,

```
$('#add-item .footer BUTTON')
```

PhpStorm says this is inefficient. I know I can rewrite it to

```
$('#add-item').find('footer').find('BUTTON')
```

Also, when I use `$('#add-item')`, I can cache it like:

```
var addItemElem = $('#add-item');
```

The question is, how important is this actually?  Will you really experience a lot of difference? Just so you know, this is for a backend admin panel and not for a website which customers can see.

If the answer is that it's really important, at which rate should I 'cache' elements? I'd assume having a lot of variables isn't really good either (but I can be wrong at that).

And if it's really important, does it matter when I use something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-item .footer BUTTON', function(){/*...*/});
```

Or how can I solve it then?

Comment: Your first example - `$('#add-item .footer BUTTON')` - isn't inefficient at all - at least in terms of jQuery patterns. If you're concerned about performance to that degree, then I'd suggest you shouldn't use jQuery at all. For 95% of cases it's more than fast enough though.

Comment: I just say whet PhpStorm says. PhpStorm says it's inefficient and points out on using `.find('')`.

Comment: Your last example is a delegated event handler, and is logically different to the previous example.

Comment: In real terms theres not much in it: https://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find. However the difference between them is so minute I'd not worry about it. To be honest I'd disable warnings like that in PHPStorm

Comment: If you're doing this sort of stuff once in response to some sort of user input, eg a button click, you really don't need to worry about it.  If you're doing it tons of times within a loop, then you _may_ need to start worrying about it, but it'll generally still be fine.

Comment: Thanks, understood!

Comment: Easiest option is to try the two different versions, in a real world scenario - eg when you click the button.  You will not see a difference.   The second *may* be more efficient than the first, but "more" is relative and shaving 0.001ms over maintainability really isn't worth it (unless as said before you're running the same selectors 1000s of times, in which case always cache the highest).   More info here: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: I'd say this `var addItemElem = $('#add-item');` is pretty important. If you do `$("#add-item")` 100 times, you would search the DOM tree every time just to find this one element. If you cache the reference, you can use it right away and search for the element only once.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov Yeah thanks, I see, I already thought that but just wanted to be sure.